A scaling system that is progressing towards creating a complex but elementary object
So, I was thinking about simple and elementary structures made from building blocks but how scale would affect such structures.
As a thought experiment, let's consider a cubic machine of size x within this cube there is a fixed amount of building blocks. Now, within every 30 seconds the cube will expand twice its size (i.e., size of cube = x*2) followed by 30 seconds of no expansion at which time the building blocks will be rearranged by this cubic machine into structures (for the analogy think of LEGO pieces, which will be constructed into buildings) so after the first expansion say small houses but a numerous amount were constructed after the second expansion a lesser amount of bigger houses were constructed after the third expansion an even lesser amount yet individually bigger house models were constructed and after a while after the nth expansion, one single large house the size of the Empire State building, now what happens after (n+1)th expansion do the blocks remain the way they are (i.e., unconstructed) or do they actually go ahead and construct a big building (like the Empire State) of a similar size like that of the previous one? I ask this because during the progression it seems that complexity and unification of building blocks and parts arise, but I wasn't sure about the last step because the maximal state has been reached.
Using any proper use of logic, what would the outcome be after n+1th expansion?
For thought-experimental purpose, assume that the machine is programmed to create higher complexity and unification with every progression

I'm voting to close as opinion-based, because it seems like this is speculation on the behaviour of a specific theoretical machine, so as it stands I'm not sure it's answerable.

@Kaia Yes it is a purely hypothetical machine but I am trying to see the soundness of reason if applied to said hypothetical machine, that is why I said it is a thought experiment.

I think you may get more assistance on this, maybe, on Math Stackexchange.  Highly suggest that you attempt to formalize as much as you can of the math.

I guess my point is that the hypothetical machine is underspecified
